# Is there an easy way to find what the minimum required version for CMake should be?

Tags: cmake, version, compatibility

Is there a convenient way to find what the minimum compatible CMake version should be (besides testing it with every single version)? I'm looking for a tool that will parse my CMakeLists.txt, find all the features I'm using, look up the CMake version they were added, and spit out the maximum. A quick look though `cmake --help` didn't show an option to do this. Is there an external tool that will do this for me?

Comment: There is not, no. Set your minimum to the version you actually use to develop your build. Newer is significantly better in CMake-land.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of now, there is no such tool. This is because there are a number of problems with creating such a tool.

Most importantly is that CMake has never made any promises of forwards-compatibility. Listfiles authored with a *newer* version of CMake have never been guaranteed to work with *older* versions, regardless what `cmake_minimum_required` setting appears. This is due to several factors: new features added, improved logic in Find modules and compiler detection, and so on. Basically anything that doesn't break old code, but makes newer code more intelligent and robust, even without source changes.

Thus, a tool that only checked for new features (like generator expressions) would miss out on changes to other parts of the overall system.

This means any such tool would have to model CMake so closely that it would be easier to simply automate running an old CMake version and testing the build. If you feel you need to do this, you should automate it yourself.

Taking a step back, CMake is amazingly, ludicrously easy to upgrade and you can save yourself and others a lot of backwards compatibility headaches like this by simply sidestepping the issue. Use a recent version, declare it as a minimum and encourage your users to upgrade. On Linux, Kitware provides statically linked executables for x86 and arm that require nothing besides libc. I have never heard of these executables not working. I use them on old Raspberry Pis. I have yet to see any remotely valid reason to support versions of CMake older than a year or so.